# How to use case properly in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am getting a minor error with the following SQL code the reason of which I don't understand.

I am using AWS Athena.

```sql
SELECT 
    icustay_id, 
    itemid, 
    date_diff('second', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', starttime) AS starttime, 
    date_diff('second', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', endtime) AS endtime,
    CASE WHEN itemid IN (30120,221906,30047) AND rateuom='mcg/kg/min' THEN CAST(rate AS DECIMAL(10,3))
FROM mimiciii.inputevents_mv
WHERE itemid IN (30128,30120,30051,221749,221906,30119,30047,30127,221289,222315,221662,30043,30307) 
ORDER BY icustay_id, itemid, starttime
```

Following is the error.

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the
>   StartQueryExecution operation: line 2:1: extraneous input 'case'
>   expecting {, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING',
>   'LIMIT', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT'} unable to rollback

Comment: can you post your complete `select` statement including `FROM` clause?

Comment: You're missing an `END` (and possibly an `ELSE ...`) on your `CASE` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for [Case expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html) is :

```
CASE
WHEN boolean condition THEN result
[WHEN ...]
[ELSE result]
END
```

You are missing `END` in your select statement. just add `END` keyword after your `then` condition as in below query. It should work fine.

```
query_vaso_mv = """
select icustay_id, itemid, date_diff('second', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00', starttime) as starttime, date_diff('second', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00', endtime) as endtime,
case when itemid in (30120,221906,30047) and rateuom='mcg/kg/min' then cast(rate as DECIMAL(10,3)) end 
from mimiciii.inputevents_mv
where itemid in (30128,30120,30051,221749,221906,30119,30047,30127,221289,222315,221662,30043,30307) 
order by icustay_id, itemid, starttime
"""
```